# Why can't I log into data.stackexchange using Facebook?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Shouldn't I be able to use same account for both? Unless they aren't really related and then indeed I need two account?

---

On Stack Overflow I can log in using Facebook:

[image]

But https://data.stackexchange.com/ doesn't offer Facebook.

I really don't want to create another account on Google just for that. And my guess is I will end up with two different accounts on Stack Overflow too.

[image]

Comment: This should maybe be on http://meta.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @BSMP this is great, I can create an account on meta.stackexchange.com using facebook but not in data.stackexchange, I even got the +100 bonus

Comment: Looks like someone already asked about this 3 years ago: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141685/no-facebook-log-in-for-stackexchange-data-explorer I guess there hasn't been enough interest to make it happen.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza From what I understand, data.stackexchange isn't _exactly_ a Stack Exchange site- What I mean by that is, by my understanding, different people maintain it than the regular SO team, and it is built with a different code base. That would be why on _any other_ Stack Exchange network site, you can use Facebook, yet that particular site can still be not set up for it. Note, and I did check this, that using the same login there does _not_ connect that account to your Stack Exchange network account. They are totally separate.

Comment: Anyone interested implementing this, may start here https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/blob/master/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Views/Account/LogIn.cshtml

Comment: This feels incredibly strange to me and strangely frustrating, too.  I'd like to have only one stack account, really.